# Real IP (Domains and Subtomains) on Bare Metal Cluster with MatalLB and Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

help me figure it out.

I have a Bare Metal Kubernetes cluster with three nodes, each node has a public ip.
I have installed MetalLB and IngressController.

It is not clear to me which IP should I redirect domains and subdomains to so that they can be resolved by the Ingress Controller?

I need to initially define on which node the Ingress Controller will be launched?
I need to install the Ingress Controller, and then look at the worker node, on which it will be installed and send all domains or subdomains there?
What happens if, after restarting the cluster, the ingress controller will be deployed on another node?

All the tutorials I've seen show how it works locally or with a cloud load balancer.

Help me understand how this should work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when you install MetalLB, you configure a pool of addresses which can be used to assign new IPs at LoadBalancer services whenever they are created. Such IP addresses need to be available, they cannot be created out of nothing of course.. they could be in lease from your hosting provider for example.

If instead you have a private Bare Metal cluster which serves only your LAN network, you could just select a private range of IP addresses which are not used.

Then, once MetalLB is running, what happens is the following:

- Someone / something creates a `LoadBalancer` services (an HELM Chart, a user with a definition, with commands, etc)
- The newly created service needs an external IP. MetalLB will select one address from the configured selected range and assign it to that service
- MetalLb will start to announce using standard protocol that the IP address can now be reached by contacting the cluster, it can work either in `Layer2` mode (one node of the cluster holds that additional IP address) or `BGP` (true load balancing across all nodes of the cluster)

From that point, you can just reach the new service by contacting this newly assigned IP address (which is NOT the ip of any of the cluster nodes)

Usually, the Ingress Controller will just bring a LoadBalancer service (which will grab an external IP address from MetalLb) and then, you can reach hte Ingress Controller from that IP.

As for your other questions, you don't need to worry about where the Ingress Controller is running or similar, it will be automatically handled.

The only thing you may want to do is to make the domain names which you want to serve point to the external IP address assigned to the Ingress Controller.

---

Some docs:

- MetalLB [explanations](https://metallb.universe.tf/concepts/)
- Bitnami MetalLB [chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/metallb)
- LoadBalancer service [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer)

Comment: Wow. Thanks for such very good explanation.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then in MetalLB I need to define only 1 public IP of a node. 
Then install IngressController (Traefik / Nginx ...) as LoadBalancer.
Then MetalLB will give a single IP to my IngressController?

This is not an internal network, the servers are visible on the Internet.

What happens if the node with loadBalancer IP will be unavailable?
Or should I specify all 3 public IPs in MetalLB for security?
Then if the node with this ip is not available, will I have to change the ip in the DNS provider to the node that works?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually you need to assign **other** IP addresses as the range which can be used by MetalLB. If you wanted to expose your service on the IP address of one of your nodes you could just use NodePort. LoadBalancing with MetalLb is something more, you get a new IP address  which you can reach so you don't have a single point of failure (AKA the single node you were trying to reach)

Comment: Thanks.

Then I still didn't quite understand.
It turns out that I don't really need MetalLB in this case.
I need to deploy Traefik deployment to some node, open 80/443 ports and then redirect all subdomains to this node.
I have 1 cluster, Traefik will dynamically recognize new services.

Or advise me how to make all subdomains routes on Traefik, which would further redirect traffic to Kubernetes services?
I've read about this topic for a long time, but I can't put the picture together.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, what do you basically want is to expose Traefik on one of the cluster nodes but at ports 80 and 443? I think that what you are searching could be hostNetwork plus a node affinity to force the Pod at running on a specific node of the cluster. But in general, it is way better to use true Load Balancing (but you need another public ip that can be given in lease to your bare metal nodes from your network provider)

Comment: Yes, I have already read and understood that. I do this, but in both popular ingress controllers it is to my case that there are open bugs.
Traefik cannot start because the helm chart is made so that there is no access https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/issues/336
Nginx. When trying to orchestrate LEtsEncrypt, it constantly returns 301 because it is misconfigured. Now I am looking for how to solve one of two problems.
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative (especially when you want "static" ip addresses) I should mention HAProxy, installed external to kubernetes cluster in a bare_server/vm/lxc_container/etc. and configured to send all incoming 80/433 traffic to the NodePort of ingress controller on all kubernetes workers (if no ingress pod is running on that worker traffic will be forwarded by kubernetes).

Of course, nowadays ip addresses are also "cattle", not "pets" anymore, so MetalLB is more of a "kubernetish" solution, but who knows ...

This is the link describing HAProxy solution (I am not affiliated with the author):

https://itnext.io/bare-metal-kubernetes-with-kubeadm-nginx-ingress-controller-and-haproxy-bb0a7ef29d4e